# Angular 2 post request done twice

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 app with one method in my service that calls the web server twice, when it should call it once.

in the session.service.ts

```
createSession(sessionName:any)
{
    return this._http.post( this._sessionUrl + "/create/"+sessionName.sessionName,{}).map((res: Response) => res)
    .do(data => console.log('Session created'))
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and in the component

```
createSession(name: string): void {
     this._sessionService.createSession(name).subscribe(
     () => this.RedirectToSessionPage(),
     () => this.ShowError()
     );
```

}

I have been reading and tried adding  .publish().refCount() and .share(), but still going two times to the server. Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: Not with oly the code code you posted. Post a plunkr reproducing the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you're not being confused by an OPTIONS preflight?

Comment: What kind of session you creating?

Comment: its just an object called session that contains participants, nothing special

Comment: @JBNizet Don't suggest that people move code out of their question; suggest that they post a [mcve] in the question itself, as is required to be on-topic.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe alluded to it sounds like you are seeing both the preflight OPTIONS request and then the subsequent POST.
The preflight is used when accessing data from remote servers (servers not co-located with your angular 2 frontend). And determines negotiates how the server can be accessed for Cross Origin Requests. (CORS)

Easiest way to check if this is whats going on is via the developer tools of whatever browser your using (for Chrome press F12 navigate to Network tab and watch as your http request is made).

This should give you an indication of if it's an OPTIONS then POST (CORS) or if you are indeed making an identical call twice (in which case a plunkr will likely be needed!)

Hope helps, sorry if this was obvious!

Comment: Another option would be to use a 3rd party software like https://www.wireshark.org/ to monitor the network traffic to see what is really going on. I agree that it could be the preflight request (pretty confusing :D )

Comment: Thanks, I will try today!